# Overhead from using one network account

Tags: ieee-802.11, authentication

Theoretical question. If using WPA2 Enterprise authentication and radius, would there be adverse effects from say, 300 devices authenticating with the same network account?

For example,

John, Sam, and Mark use the account User1 to connect to the WLAN. So do 297 other employees. Does this create an overhead issue or cause a flaky connection?

Not asking about monitoring issues, just connectivity. Thanks.

Comment: Authentication has nothing to do with how the network performs. You should be concerned more about the number of WAPs necessary to service 300 users. Your performance will suffer greatly after about 20 or 30 users on a WAP.

Comment: Not a lot of point in using WPA2E if you're going to treat it like WPA2P - or, theoretically it stinks, but not for the reason you are asking about.

Comment: @RonMaupin I can have 2-5 devices on an AP and it will disconnect and reconnect intermittently.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Trying to connect student iPads to the WLAN without allowing their iPhones. PSK might work but kids will put them on their phones instead of their iPads if we don't touch each device ourselves.

Comment: "_I can have 2-5 devices on an AP and it will disconnect and reconnect intermittently._" That can be any number of things. You may have cheap WAPs, or the WLC is configured incorrectly, but it should have nothing to do with authentication.

Comment: @kenta How would re-using the same account stop iPhones from getting on your network?  The only solution here would be device certificates, that are only permitted on trusted devices.

Comment: @RonMaupin WAPs are supposed to support 30 clients.

Comment: @BenjaminDale because we don't share credentials.

Comment: @Kenta - your comments mention that you don't want to touch each device, but if you give out a single WPA2E credential, you may as well be handing out a PSK.  Maybe you can explain it a bit better

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Switched to PSK, no disconnections anymore.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.